# Misleading lack of freespace on apt-get install

Tags: 12.04, apt, kubuntu

I'm trying to upgrade some packages, seems they already got  downloaded sucessfuly, but everytime I try to install them I get a translated version of "Not enough space available on device". The error of the following message points to /usr

```
mcloud@Sanctuary:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto                                                                       
Construindo árvore de dependências                                                                      
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto                                                                    
Corrigindo dependências... Pronto                                                                       
Os seguintes pacotes foram instalados automaticamente e já não são necessários:                         
python-levenshtein python-enchant python-vobject python-utidylib python-iniparse python-dateutil      
Use 'apt-get autoremove' para removê-los.
Os pacotes extra a seguir serão instalados:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-25 parley-data
Os NOVOS pacotes a seguir serão instalados:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-25
Os pacotes a seguir serão atualizados:
  parley-data
1 pacotes atualizados, 1 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 4 não atualizados.
389 pacotes não totalmente instalados ou removidos.
É preciso baixar 0 B/15.7 MB de arquivos.
Depois desta operação, 56.2 MB adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Você quer continuar [S/n]? Y
(Lendo banco de dados ... 306928 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
Desempacotando linux-headers-3.2.0-25 (de .../linux-headers-3.2.0-25_3.2.0-25.40_all.deb) ...
dpkg: erro processando /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-25_3.2.0-25.40_all.deb (--unpack):
 não conseguiu criar `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-25/arch/arm/include/asm/floppy.h.dpkg-new' (enquanto processava `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-25/arch/arm/include/asm/floppy.h'): Não há espaço disponível no dispositivo
Nenhum relatório apport escrito pois a mensagem de erro indica erro de disco cheio
dpkg-deb: erro: subprocesso colar foi finalizado pelo sinal (Pipe quebrado)
Preparando para substituir parley-data 4:4.8.2-0ubuntu1 (usando .../parley-    data_4%3a4.8.3-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb) ...
Desempacotando substituto parley-data ...
Processando gatilhos para hicolor-icon-theme ...
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.2.0-25_3.2.0-25.40_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The system is mounted as this (notice 242GB availabe on / which is where /usr is):

```
mcloud@Sanctuary:~$ df
Sist. Arq.                 1K-blocos      Usad   Dispon. Uso% Montado em
/dev/mapper/Sanctuary-root 481848016 214758976 242995868  47% /
udev                         1013184         4   1013180   1% /dev
tmpfs                         410308       900    409408   1% /run
none                            5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                         1025768      1460   1024308   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda5                     233331    184948     35936  84% /boot
```

/etc/fstab contents:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
/dev/mapper/Sanctuary-root /               ext4    noatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=c09adf3c-9e67-4dc3-8940-33cc8bd98f4e /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/Sanctuary-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/scd0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
LABEL=root / ext3 defaults,noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

This started happening after upgrading the system to 12.04

Answer (score 1):

I think that your inode space is full. sudo tune2fs -l /dev/root

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/root
<snapped>
Inode count:              2445984
Block count:              9764864
Reserved block count:     488268
Free blocks:              6806062
Free inodes:              2265142
<snapped>
```

Comment: if you have a ton of files it could be inodes.